# Dump XML into Database

Tags: mysql, xml, ubuntu

I am using Mysql 5.1 and Ubuntu. I am having XML file which is having many child and sub-child nodes. For each child and sub-child I have to generate one table each. Can we dump such one XML to multiple table? how? I check for Load XML function for Mysql but it is not there in 5.1. Which version I have to install for Load XML function.

Comment: Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-xml.html